# Padding string to left

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

How can one pad a string to left in objective c.
E.g if I have an integer value of 6 I want it to be displayed as 06.

I use `stringByPaddingToLength:` but it pads it to the right like 60.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
+ (NSString *)formatValue:(int)value forDigits:(int)zeros {
    NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%0%dd", zeros]; 
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:format,value];
}
```

Comment: What if I want to add 0s to left of a string instead of an integer? So if I have hello I want 000hello?

Comment: Instead of constructing a variable format, why not just use the variable field length, e.g. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0*d", zeros, value];`?

Comment: stringWithFormat is not the greatest.. I woulb be

Comment: What if you are starting with an NSString?  I've tried `[stringWithFormat:@"%05%@", myString]` but that reports `Data argument not used byFormatString` and removing the `%` before the `@` reports `Flag '0' results in undefined behaviour with '@' conversion specifier`.

Answer (score 78):

This one pads left with 10 zeroes.

```
NSString *padded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Padded left with zeros: %010d", 65];
```

Comment: What if 65 was an NSString?  Is there a formatter to handle that without doing a type conversion?

Answer (score 14):

Clumsy, but it'll do the job.

```
@implementation NSString (LeftPadding)

- (NSString *)stringByPaddingTheLeftToLength:(NSUInteger)newLength withString:(NSString *)padString startingAtIndex:(NSUInteger)padIndex
{
    if ([self length] <= newLength)
        return [[@"" stringByPaddingToLength:newLength - [self length] withString:padString startingAtIndex:padIndex] stringByAppendingString:self];
    else
        return [[self copy] autorelease];
}

@end
```

Then you can do:

```
NSString *test1 = [@"6" stringByPaddingTheLeftToLength:10 withString:@"0" startingAtIndex:0];
// test1 = "0000000006"

NSString *test2 = [@"asdf" stringByPaddingTheLeftToLength:10 withString:@"qwer" startingAtIndex:0];
// test2 = "qwerqwasdf"

NSString *test3 = [@"More than ten characters" stringByPaddingTheLeftToLength:10 withString:@"bamboo" startingAtIndex:0];
// test3 = "More than ten characters"

NSString *test4 = [test3 stringByPaddingTheLeftToLength:100 withString:test2 startingAtIndex:0];
// test4 = "qwerqwasdfqwerqwasdfqwerqwasdf...qwerqMore than ten characters"
```

Comment: Not Clumsy at all! Especially when the object to be padded is a string, not a number. BTW, the `startingAtIndex ` parameter is not necessary any more.

Answer (score 8):

Old thread, I know, but this is a handy way to left pad.  I have it my Util class.  You can adapt it to right pad if needed.  The best part is that it works with whatever padding you want.

```
+ (NSString *) leftPadString:(NSString *)s withPadding:(NSString *)padding {
    NSString *padded = [padding stringByAppendingString:s];
    return [padded substringFromIndex:[padded length] - [padding length]];
}
```

ARC and non-ARC compliant.  :)

To call it, use `[Util leftPadString:@"42" withPadding:@"0000"];`.

You could also put it in a category on NSString for an even easier call like `[@"42" stringByLeftPadding:@"0000"]`.

Both give you 0042.

Comment: Thank you, and right pad string is here for anyone who wants it: - (NSString *) rightPadString:(NSString *)s withPadding:(NSString *)padding {
    NSString *padded = [s stringByAppendingString:padding];
    return [padded substringToIndex:[padding length]];
}

Comment: "ARC and non-ARC compliant."  How times have changed... :)

Answer (score 4):

for completness (using `*` placeholder):

```
NSString *paddedNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0*d", amountOfZeros, numberNSInteger]
```