# How to format NSString for same letter size all the time?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
 str=[NSString stringWithFormat:
             @"Person1:%7@,Person2:%7@,Person3:%7@",
@"Ann",@"Peter",@"jackson"];
```

I want to display it like:

```
Ann     Peter      jackson
```

instead of:

```
Ann,Peter,jackson
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/8651226/95976

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pad NSString with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651210/how-to-pad-nsstring-with-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString *original = @"Ann,Peter,Jackson";
    NSArray *originalParts = [original componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString new];
    for (NSString *string in originalParts) {
        [newString appendString:[string stringByPaddingToLength:string.length + 7 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Finished Product: %@", newString);
```

Will output:

```
Finished Product: Ann       Peter       Jackson
```