# Swift how to make a string align to right

Tags: string, swift, right-align

how to make a string align to right? For now, I know how to make a string align to left by using `stringByPaddingToLength`. Any idea for align to right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Padding string to left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964322/padding-string-to-left)

Comment: @ozgur I wanna it align to right, not left.

Comment: `stringByPaddingToLength` pads to right already. The link I've shared explains how to do the opposite *(pad to left)* using `stringByPaddingToLength`.

Comment: *gazes into the future* `swiftpm install leftpad`

Comment: Could you give us example of results you wants ?

Answer (score 3):

A possible implementation (explanations inline):

```
extension String {
    func stringByLeftPaddingToLength(newLength : Int) -> String {
        let length = self.characters.count
        if length < newLength {
            // Prepend `newLength - length` space characters:
            return String(count: newLength - length, repeatedValue: Character(" ")) + self
        } else {
            // Truncate to the rightmost `newLength` characters:
            return self.substringFromIndex(startIndex.advancedBy(length - newLength))
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let s = "foo"
let padded = s.stringByLeftPaddingToLength(6)
print(">" + padded + "<")
// >   foo<
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
extension String {
    func stringByLeftPaddingTo(length newLength : Int) -> String {
        let length = self.characters.count
        if length < newLength {
            // Prepend `newLength - length` space characters:
            return String(repeating: " ", count: newLength - length) + self
        } else {
            // Truncate to the rightmost `newLength` characters:
            return self.substring(from: self.index(endIndex, offsetBy: -newLength))
        }
    }
}
```